# Any way to get the text value of a key that's stored in the database? (replit node.js)

Tags: node.js, key, key-value, replit, replit-database

I kept trying to find a solution but couldn't find it anywhere, I'm using this for my discord bot and I want it to send the text value of a stored key in the database as a text message to discord.
How do I do this??

I tried things such as `message.channel.send(database.get("key name", value}))`
But didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.